# Any Python package or app to simulate high-frequency wind data?

Tags: python-2.7, simulation

I have 10minute average wind data for a whole year and I would like to simulate 1-second wind data using the measured data with the 10minute data.

Is there any Python package or app with GUI to do so?

Comment: so you have 10mins of wind data, and you want it be simulated in 1 second?

Comment: I have the average and standard deviation of every 10minutes and I want to simulate the 1second data within each 10minute period. It is related with Spectrum simulation,FFT, etc...

Comment: its still not making sense, you want to a certain "1 second" in the period on a graph/map?